# Use jQuery to change row color unless checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have some table rows with checkboxes.

```
<table cellpadding="0" class="action_table">
    <tbody class="action_table_body">
        <tr class="action_table_row">
            <td class="action_table_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="chkbx_1"></td>
            <td class="action_table_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="chkbx_2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm toggling the color of the rows on mouseover events.

```
$(".action_table_row").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({background:'#FCF6CF'});
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({background:'#F3F3F3'});
});
```

I also want to highlight rows that are checked:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({background:'#ff0000'});
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({background:'#F3F3F3'});
    });
});
```

The problem is when these two interact.  I want to maintain the highlighting if a row is checked, thus overriding the mouseenter/mouseleave.

I tried this, but it seems to operate across all rows/checkboxes instead of the specific row with the checked checkbox.

```
$(".action_table_row").mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this + ':checkbox').attr('checked') == false) {
        $(this).css({background:'#FCF6CF'});
    }
}).mouseleave(function() {
    if ($(this + ':checkbox').attr('checked') == false) {
        $(this).css({background:'#F3F3F3'});
    }
});
```

How do I keep the css from changing if a row's checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS classes and the `not` selector. Also note that I replace `parent` with `closest('tr')`.

Not changing checked rows:

```
$(".action_table_row:not(.checked)").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({background:'#FCF6CF'});
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({background:'#F3F3F3'});
});
```

Setting the `checked` class instead:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('checked');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('checked');
    });
});
```

Try to avoid using inline styling as much as you can. It's a lot easier to handle all styling in the stylesheet instead of in several places.

Comment: Interesting.  I like this approach.  I'm not getting it to work though.  I checked and the 'checked' class is definitely getting attached ("action_table_row checked"), but the mouseenter/leave is getting triggered anyway.

Comment: It should work, but it doesnt ;/. However, I added a check inside the `mouseover`. I also show how you can blend the bk colors (remove the `if` and ): http://jsfiddle.net/Byvrb/2/